# How do I use a static IP in Ubuntu 17.10 and newer?

Tags: networking, netplan

I changed config from dhcp to static (192.168.0.17), but still getting a dhcp assigned (192.168.0.141) IP. I don't know where else to check... any idea?

**ifconfig**

```
ens33: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.141  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe87:6981  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0c:29:87:69:81  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 43080139  bytes 55213169928 (55.2 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 1  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 17923871  bytes 1406116280 (1.4 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 56350  bytes 6166732 (6.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 56350  bytes 6166732 (6.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**nmcli d**

```
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION
ens33   ethernet  unmanaged  --
lo      loopback  unmanaged  --
```

**/etc/network/interfaces**

```
# /etc/network/interfaces -- configuration file for ifup(8), ifdown(8)
# Generated by debian-installer.

# The loopback interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#The primary network interface
auto ens33
iface ens33 inet static
address 192.168.0.17
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1
```

**/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf**

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

**uname -a**

```
Linux server 4.13.0-16-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 11 18:35:14 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: You brought the interface down and back up again?

Comment: Yes:

sudo service network-manager restart

But, still dhcp ip showing 192.168.0.141

Strange that I can connect to 192.168.0.17 and 192.168.0.141 .. even ping both..

Comment: Try using `ifdown ens33; ifup ens33` as root.

Comment: sudo ifdown ens33:
ifdown: interface ens33 not configured

Comment: Is Network Manager running in a server??

Comment: its a server with GUI

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Networking is handled by netplan by default in Ubuntu Server 17.10. I suggest that you edit the `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml` file to read:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens33:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.0.17/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,192.168.0.1]
```

Exit and save your changes by running the command:

```
sudo netplan apply
```

Please note and follow the spacing and indentation.

Comment out all the ens33 stanzas in `/etc/network/interfaces`. Reboot.

Any improvement?

Comment: Wow, I couldn't find that information in the internet. Why every release people change the way linux is configured? Miss old 90's era, where the Ethernet device was "eth0" and inet.conf .. :/ .. Do I need to disable that "Network Manager" as well ?

Comment: Generally, a server runs headless with no desktop environment; i.e. GUI and therefor Network Manager is not running or even installed. If you wish to run NM, I'd first try setting the static IP there. I suspect it will work perfectly. Please clarify your intentions. Also, what is your current netplan file? `ls /etc/netplan`?

Comment: it worked as you mentioned. (01-netcfg.yaml). I need to run some X apps with this server.

Comment: If  it is now working as expected, I would make no further changes. If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour

Comment: @chili555 where did you find that info about netplan?

Comment: @guntbert https://websiteforstudents.com/configuring-static-ips-ubuntu-17-10-servers/ and I went through the exercise a few days ago on another question.

Comment: Also see: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Netplan and: https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Ubuntu-17.10-Netplan