# static IP not remaining after network disconnection

Tags: networking, server, ethernet, ip

I'm having issues in Ubuntu Server 17.10 when configuring static IP through the /etc/network/interfaces file.

Every time I start the server or there is a network disconnection I get a different IP than the one I wrote on the interfaces file, then I had to manually do the `sudo ifdown eno1 && sudo ifup -v eno1` or `sudo service networking restart` to get the IP I wrote on the /etc/network/interfaces file.

Any idea of how I can solve this? I'll like to always have the IP address I wrote on the /etc/network/interfaces file.

Currently my /etc/network/interfaces looks like this:

```
# My eno1 configuration
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet static
 address X.X.X.X #Here is the IP address assigned by sysadmin
 netmask 255.255.255.240
 gateway X.X.X.X #Here gateway assigned by sysadmin
 dns-nameservers X.X.X.X #Here DNS assigned by sysadmin

# The loopback interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/977833/cant-change-ubuntu-17-to-static-ip

Comment: @chili555 It  worked great. Specially the link you supplied on the other thread: https://websiteforstudents.com/configuring-static-ips-ubuntu-17-10-servers/