# How do I create a YAML file in order to set a static IP for my /etc/netplan directory? Server 18.04 LTS

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, nginx, static-ip

I currently do not have any YAML files in my `/etc/netplan` directory than I can edit in order to set a static IP for my Ubuntu 18 server. I have tried:

```
sudo netplan generate
```

It returns no errors but there is also no new files (or any files for that matter) created under `/etc/netplan`.
Can I use nano to create a file a save it with a `.yaml` extension and still use

```
sudo netplan apply
```

in order to update my Ethernet interface settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is exactly what I suggest that you do. Here is a sample file to get started: [Can't change Ubuntu 17.10 to use a static IP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/977833/cant-change-ubuntu-17-10-to-use-a-static-ip/977838#977838)

Of course, substitute your exact details here. Also, indentation, spacing, etc. are crucial. Proofread carefully.